# How do I use the SDK facebook application to write on a user's wall?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, sdk

I am writing an app using Microsoft SDK for Facebook Platform (a desktop app)

My question is:

How can I write on the wall of my users, that thay are using my app and
to leave a photo of my app icon on their wall?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Post to the `me\feed` object in the Graph API using a user access token.  Many examples of this on SO as well as on Facebook's developers site.